# ASP.NET I cannot get the model to bring data back to the controller. It is always 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

So I have been working on this for a minute and can't figure out why my data is always 0. NumJuror is simply a model to hold the single int I need back from the view.

My Contollers:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(NumJuror model)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ListPool", model.numberOfJurors);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ListPool(int numberOfJurors)
    {
        JurySQLDAO jurySQLDAO = new JurySQLDAO();
        JuryPool jury = new JuryPool(); 
        int rows = jurySQLDAO.GetRows();
        RandomID randomID = new RandomID();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfJurors; i++)
        {
            Juror juror = new Juror();
            juror = jurySQLDAO.GetJuror(randomID.getRandomID(rows));
            jury.Pool.Add(juror);
        }

        return View(jury);
    }
```

My view looks like this:

```
    @model Iudices2._0.Models.NumJuror
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Jury Selection Portal</h2>
<p>Please enter the number of jurors need for this pool:</p>
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Indexview " method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="number" asp-for="numberOfJurors">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I've debugged several times and no matter what I put in the index, model always comes back as 0 but with a valid model state.

Answer (score 0):

Try Change it to :

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post">
```